# A-frame images not loading properly in react for mobile ios safari. I am getting a black box instead of the image

Tags: ios, reactjs, image, aframe

Everything seems to work fine on android but ios consistently give me a block box.

```
<Entity primitive="a-assets">
     {userState.photo_memory_filepath && !loading ? (
              <img
                id="first-image"
                src={`${GOOGLE_CLOUD_BUCKET_PUBLIC}/${userState.photo_memory_filepath}`}
                crossOrigin="Anonymous"
              />
            ) : null}
   </Entity>
```

Later I have

```
{userState.photo_memory_filepath && !loading ? (
            <Entity
              primitive="a-image"
              src="#first-image"
              position="0 3 -9"
              width="2"
              height="2"
              material="side: double"
              id="first-image-view"
            ></Entity>
          ) : null}
```

Loading is a redux state that is set to true before making requests.
Everything works fine on desktop web and android but ios is screwing me over. Oh I also tried createObjectURL which also worked for both desktop and android but with no avail to ios. I'm really believing IOS mobile webapp dev is cursed

Comment: I am getting the same issue -- works on any other device (desktop and android) but it seems like iOS safari won't load the asset/material.  Just a black box.  Did you figure it out?